# Como alterar o valor de uma variável que está dentro de uma função através de outra função?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, variáveis, parâmetros

Já vi perguntas semelhantes aqui no SO, mas ainda não consegui resolver a seguinte situação, onde tenho a função abaixo que está dentro de um script externo:

```
function updateScript(marcador, a, b) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.id = widget_config.script_id;
        script.src = widget_config.home_page + '/feeds/posts/default/-/' + marcador + '?alt=json-in-script&start-index=' + a + '&max-results=' + b + '&callback=grabList';

    if (document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id)) {
        var oldScript = document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id);
        oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Meu propósito é, dentro do meu arquivo HTML, acrescentar um valor diferente à variável `marcador` a depender de onde eu chamar a possível função que passe essa string para a o `marcador`. Ex.: Em algum lugar, eu quero definir o texto **CSS** como o marcador; em outro, o texto **HTML**, e assim sucessivamente.

No caso, meu HTML está assim:

```
<script src="endereço-do-script-acima.js"></script>
<script>updateScript("nome-do-marcador")</script>
```

É possível?

Comment: Você não faz isso, não faz sentido, você provavelmente quer fazer outra coisa. Se der eu volto aqui mais tarde.

Comment: Tudo bem, @Maniero Se puder me ajudar, cara, fico grato!

Comment: Colocar como parâmetro da função não vai te servir?

Comment: @GeekSilva Tentei como parâmetro, mas não funcionou. Atualizei a pergunta para ficar mais claro como está meu código até o momento.

Comment: Foi lançada alguma exception? Ainda não entendi muito bem o objetivo.

Comment: Meu intuito, na verdade, é evitar a repetição de um grande número de código, @GeekSilva . Tenho 8 DIVs para mostrar em cada uma as publicações de determinado marcador. Tenho um script que faz essa "categorização", porque é só eu colocar o nome do marcador dentro da variável script.src que funciona. Só que estou tentando uma forma de isolar essa variável com o nome do marcador e torná-la dinâmica, porque, do contrário, precisarei usar todo o código 8 vezes, sendo que se eu alterar só essa linha, resolve meu problema.

Comment: Agora compreendi. Na utilização do parâmetro, o que não funcionou?

Comment: @GeekSilva O console diz que o parâmetro não foi encontrado.

Comment: Você teria como colocar esse código no JS Fiddle?

Comment: Posso enviar, sim, @GeekSilva Parece que descobri uma possível razão do erro. Me parece que o código só aceita uma lista ordenada e uma div com ID específico. Estou fazendo os testes aqui e qualquer novidade, aviso. Obrigado!

Comment: Beleza. Pois é achei bem estranho ele não reconhecer o parâmetro.

Comment: @GeekSilva Realmente, cara, o problema que estou tendo é por conta que o código só funciona em uma instância. Consegui isolar a variável marcador, declarando-a externamente (que era meu objetivo com a pergunta), mas não vou conseguiu fechar as 8 DIVs porque o código mescla esses marcadores em uma única DIV, mas aí é outra história. Para todo efeito, a pergunta em si já tem uma resposta. Muito obrigado pela prestatividade, garoto!

Comment: Imagina. Precisando tamo ae

Answer (score 1):

Alguns erros me foram apresentador por não ter seu HTML completo e não conseguir pegar alguns elementos pelo ID, mas acredito que esse código irá funcionar.

```js
function updateScript(marcador, a, b) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.id = widget_config.script_id;
        script.src = widget_config.home_page + '/feeds/posts/default/-/' + marcador + '?alt=json-in-script&start-index=' + a + '&max-results=' + b + '&callback=grabList';

    if (document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id)) {
        var oldScript = document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id);
        oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function opcaoSelecionada(val){
  
  if(val){
    updateScript(val, 0, 10)
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <select onchange="opcaoSelecionada(this.value)">
    <option value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
  </select>
</head>
```

Comment: Oi, @Kodark Obrigado pela resposta! Consegui resolver o problema declarando a variável 'marcador' dentro do HTML, fora do script. Grato pela ajuda, meu caro!